# composition of generic types in java

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I'm defining a class User, which has a generic type which extends Principal

```
public abstract class User<P extends Principal> {
}
```

And I have an action base class which should be parameterized with an user:

```
public abstract class Action<U extends User<Principal>> {
}
```

Those two classes are on muy codebase. Now, I want to use them on an specific application, so I create an implementation for Principal and User:

```
public class MyPrincipal implements Principal {
    public String getName() {
        return "Administrator";
    }
}

public class MyUser extends User<MyPrincipal>{
}
```

Once I have my user, I want to use it on an action

```
public class MyAction extends Action<MyUser>{
}
```

This last class does not compile. It complais that :

```
Bound mismatch: The type MyUser is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <U extends User<Principal>> of the type Action<U>
```

What I want is to enforce that all classes extending MyAction should be parameterized with an object that extends User, and also is parameterized by an object which implements Principal. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the bound on your `Action` class says - `U extends User<Principal>`. Since `MyUser` deoesn't extend a `User<Principal>`, but a `User<MyPrincipal>`, it won't work as you expected. A `User<MyPrincipal>` is not a `User<Principal>` (distinct types).

You can introduce another type parameter in your `Action` class, and use that in bounds of `U`:

```
public abstract class Action<P extends Principal, U extends User<P>> {
}
```

and now, you can create your `MyAction` like this:

```
public class MyAction extends Action<MyPrincipal, MyUser>{
}
```

---

Or you can also modify your class using wildcard bound:

```
public abstract class Action<U extends User<? extends Principal>> {
}
```

This way you won't need another type parameter:

```
public class MyAction extends Action<MyUser>{
}
```

---

**References:**

- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [Can I use a type parameter as part of its own bounds?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Can%20I%20use%20a%20type%20parameter%20as%20part%20of%20its%20own%20bounds%20or%20in%20the%20declaration%20of%20other%20type%20parameters?)

Comment: Yes, both option work. But my question is, why I can not define it as Action<U extends User<P extends Principal>>

Comment: @JoseLMartinez-Avial B'coz you haven't declared the type parameter `P`. A type parameter is said to be declared for a class if it comes at the top-level, and not when nested. And before using a type parameter for bounds, you must declare itself.

Answer (score 2):

Change `Action`'s signature to this (I tested this in Eclipse and it compiles):

```
public abstract class Action<U extends User<? extends Principal>>
```

By doing this, you're saying that any type of `Principal` is okay, not just base-type `Principal` objects (which of course can't be instantiated).